# Pass variable to ng-model for multi-page form

Tags: angularjs

I'm creating a multi-page form with AngularJS, and want to pass a variable to ng-model to represent which page of the form the user is on, in addition to saving the form data by page.

I tried to pass a variable to ng-model, but the variable was read as `ng-model="formData.pageID"` vs `ng-model="formData.1"`

For example:

```
formData = {'1': {},
            '2': {},
            '3': {},
            ...
           }
```

The user has the ability to add unlimited number of pages, so I can't hard count the page count.

Comment: Is `pageID` a variable that holds the page number? You probably wanted this: `ng-model="formData[pageID]"`

Comment: yes it holds the page number, thanks

Comment: @New Dev is it possible to do: `ng-model"formData[pageID].title"`

Comment: I don't know what `.title` is as you don't specify in the question, but yes, it should be possible.